# VBA Editor broken - Excel 2016 OSX

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I recently installed Excel 2016 for mac and when I launched the VBA editor the text was placed in a vertical way (line without any width) as shown in the following image. Any workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same thing on Mac OS X 10.11.3 and Excel 15.13.3 (150815), did you have any chance resolving it?

Comment: Nope..
Same goes for powerpoint, and in general for wherever the VBA editor is used.

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: Nope... nothing

Comment: Same - anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a new release (15.39.0 build 17101000) for Office Excel for Mac.

It has been released on October 10. The VBA editor is improved a lot. Most probably this issues doesn't occur anymore.

See [release notes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Release-notes-for-Office-2016-for-Mac-ed2da564-6d53-4542-9954-7e3209681a41?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)